# Equivalent of Aggregate where there is no Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have several aggregates: Deposit, Withdraw etc. Now there is a VO called Ledger, which has other related VOs as well. Ledger marks the transaction for both the Deposit and Withdraw, which ever takes place. In this case, it seems similar to making a separate aggregate(creating a folder and placing Ledger and related types into it). But DDD won't allow me that, because Aggregate roots can only be Entities.

What can be the possible solution for it? How can I categorize and place Ledger and related VOs while staying in the boundaries of DDD?

**UPDATE:**

The ledger is like a record, a transaction for each operation performed. For example, when a deposit has been made, a trade has occurred etc. So it has no state, and will be just saved once and never modified again. It is persisted for record keeping purposes.

Deposit and Withdraw both have states and a lifetime, their status will change from Pending to Confirmation, or from Pending to Cancelled. So they cannot be services.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's strange, but `Withdraw` sounds like an action, not an entity and `Ledger` sounds like something that would normally be an entity.  You'll probably need to post more information and code samples.

Answer (score 1):

From your update, it sounds as though you might have a slight terminology issue and a missing entity.

You might need to rename your `Ledger` value object to `LedgerRecord` or `LedgerEntry`.

Your missing entity might then be a `Ledger` (a ledger is like a book, a container of records or entries).  This would have a collection of `LedgerRecords`.

So you would then maybe call `Ledger.MakeEntry(text)` or maybe call `LedgerService.GetLedgerSectionByDateRange(from, to)`, which would return a `Ledger` populated with `LedgerRecords` from that date range, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, think of the rest of VOs that are part of the Ledger. Is there any hidden identity that you haven't considered before among these VOs? In that case, that would be the (root) Entity and you would have your Aggregate.

If that's not the case, you could consider whether the Ledger is a VO that is part of an Aggregate in which the root entity is Operation, where Operation is an Entity with unique identity and Withdraw and Deposit would be specializations of it.